# I want to change the color of text inside anchor tag when hovered, but CSS doesn't allow referencing class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the text color of anchor tag when hovered on the item, but how can I select anchor tag inside `services-list div:hover`.

```css
body{
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.services-list div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e5f7ef;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.services-list div:hover {
  background-color: #43ffaf;
  color: #262a33;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="services-list">
    <div>
        <p>texts</p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to denote the parent-child relationship here, try `div.services-list > div:hover`

Comment: @Rogue I want to change color of anchor tag on hovering.

Comment: Then you could make your rule (for changing the color) referenced as: `div.services-list > div:hover > a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also write rule set for anchor tag when hovered.

```css
body{
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.services-list div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e5f7ef;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.services-list div:hover {
  background-color: #43ffaf;
  color: #262a33;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.services-list div:hover > a {
  color: #262a33;
}
```

```html
<div class="services-list">
    <div>
        <p>texts</p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```